# AngularJS lost data from multipartForm directive to routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, forms, file

I am trying to build an Excel file uploader and parse the data in the routes to store it but it appears the data is lost in translation from the FormData sent in through the $http service route. I have no clue what to do! If you have any experience with this please help!

Html View:

```
    <form ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="myFile.name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" >
            <input type="file" file-model="myFile.file"/>  
        </div>
        <button ng-click="Submit()">upload me</button>
    </form>
```

Controller View:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'multipartForm', function($scope, multipartForm){
    $scope.myFile = {};
    $scope.Submit = function(){
        var uploadUrl = '/upload';
        multipartForm.post(uploadUrl, $scope.myFile);
    }
}]);
```

Service View:

```
myApp.service('multipartForm', ['$http', function($http){
    this.post = function(uploadUrl, data){
        var fd = new FormData();
        for(var key in data) {
            fd.append(key, data[key]);
        }
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.indentity,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
        });
    }
}])
```

Directive View:

```
myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function($parse){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                })
            })
        }
    }
}])
```

This is the route view where the data does not travel through.

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app
    .post('/upload', function(req, res){
        console.log(req.body);
        console.log(req.files);
    });
}
```

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads/'});
var app = express();





// if using body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
// if mongoose, require mongoose
//require('./server/config/mongoose.js');

//routes
require('./server/config/routes.js')(app);

app.listen(8000, function () {
    console.log('listening on port 8000');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simple way is to use ng-file-upload. it's the most popular AngularJS directive for file upload using HTML5 with FileAPI polyfill for unsupported browsers.

[Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-file-upload)

[Demo](https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I guess I'm just making it harder on myself than I should have.